# How to terminate a floating value upto specified decimal places

Tags: python

I want represent a floating number n=3.145678 and I want to display it as 3.14 i.e. upto two decimal place without rounding of the digits, it there any possible way in Python to do this or it will always get rounded off.

I have tried the "round()" function but I provide the value after rounding off it. i.e. it convert it to 3.15 as 5 is there at third position after decimal point.
Same is the condition with the decimal module when doing that.

Comment: n = 3.145678
formatted_n = "{:.2f}".format(n)
float_n = float(formatted_n)

Comment: The format (or f string) is useful when displaying the value, and you then don't alter how it's stored if you mean to keep precision when stored in python. Unless I've misunderstood and you mean to round up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use floor function combined with moving a decimal point to specific place:

```
import math

def floor_n_place(number, n):
    number *= 10**n
    number = math.floor(number)
    number /= 10**n
    return number

number = 3.145678
print(floor_n_place(number, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 100. Convert to int. Divide by 100

```
n = 3.145

print(int(n*100)/100)
```

**Output:**

```
3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit a float to two decimal points in Python:

```
s = str(n)
p = s[:4]
print(float(p))
```

Comment: `x = round(n, 2)` will not achieve desired result, as mention in the question it will return 3.15 when 3.14 is intended result.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the truncation of a value up to a certain decimal place. You may define an helper function that uses `math.floor`, using a base 10 multiplying factor to shift the decimal places you want to truncate on:

```
import math

def truncate_upto(value, n_digits):
    multiplying_factor = 10**n_digits
    return math.floor(value * multiplying_factor) / multiplying_factor 

x = truncate_upto(n, 2) 
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I tried the provide solution, it rounded off to nearest value.

```
import math
n = 3.145678

# Provided Solution
x = "{:.2f}".format(n)
print("Above Solution", x) # returns: Above Solution 3.15

# Other Solution
y = math.floor(n*100)/100
print("Other Solution", y) # returns: Other Solution 3.14
```

[image: Image for Same]